# How are Instance methods stored in memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, static-methods, class-method

I'm studying the C++ class method pointers and I've crossed this example:

```
class A
{
public: 

A();

void sample() {  ...method_stuff... }

void (A::*ptrToSample);

};

A::A()
{
ptrToSample = &A::sample;
}
```

Now, if I've understood correctly, *sample* is non-static, which means that I can't invoke it without an object of *A*, more precisely, if I do not create an object of *A*, also all its non-static methods and members aren't stored in memory either. 
Having said so, I get confused by the object constructor reported by the example. Shouldn't any object of *A* have a copy of *sample*? If yes, then why I have to use the *&* operator on the class scope instead of *this* operator?

Shouldn't the constructor be something like:

```
{
ptrToSample = &(this->sample);
}
```

?

Since the method is non-virtual, it shouldn't be saved in the virtual method table (right?), then where the heck is it stored? What am I missing?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 5):

First, `void (A::*ptrToSample);` must be `void (A::*ptrToSample)();`.

---

> sample is non-static, which means that I can't invoke it without an object of A

Yes.

> more precisely, if I do not create an object of A, also all its non-static methods and members aren't stored in memory either

No, methods aren't stored *in* objects. There's always a single "instance" of each method in memory, and it isn't copied when you create objects. Under the hood, methods work like regular (free) functions, but with an implicit `this` parameter.

> Shouldn't the constructor be something like: `ptrToSample = &(this->sample);`

It's hard to say why a specific syntax was choosen, but `&(this->sample)` would be somewhat misleading, since a member pointer doesn't contain a pointer to a specific object instance (so `this` would be discarded). You don't have to have an object to create a member pointer. The object needs to be provided later, when you dereference the pointer.

Comment: ehi @HolyBlackCat thank you for your response. Regarding the fact that methods work like a regular function than in why is it necessary to have an object to invoke them or declare them statically?  The first thing that comes in my mind is due to the object members, can you explain me that?  Do object methods share the same memory of static methods or virtual method table?

Comment: @Evethir *"why is it necessary to have an object to invoke"* That's their whole point, they're invoken on a specific object. As I said, they essentially have a hidden `this` parameter, pointing to the object they were called on.

Comment: thank you very much! Is there a way to see the difference between static, virtual method table and object methods either in memory or debug?